# running npm run build throws Error: server-renderer

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm trying to deploy my Vue, Laravel, InertiaJS and TailwindCSS app.

When I try to use `npm run build` on my Laravel project, I get this error:

> [vite:load-fallback] Could not load
> vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js/server-renderer (imported by
> resources/js/pages/Notifications.vue): ENOENT: no such file or
> directory, open
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\TweetyPie\vue\dist\vue.esm-bundler.js\server-renderer'
> error during build: Error: Could not load
> vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js/server-renderer (imported by
> resources/js/pages/Notifications.vue): ENOENT: no such file or
> directory, open
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\TweetyPie\vue\dist\vue.esm-bundler.js\server-renderer'

Help would be appreciated, I can give info about my code if needed

Comment: Did you run `npm install` before `npm run build`?

Comment: problem might be with your vue package try running npm  install then run npm install vue before you run npm run build

Comment: After a day, everything i had to do to forget the problem was delete a line asking for de vue.esm-bundler in my vite.config. Thanks everyone for the help :)